# Listview and data updating

Tags: android, listview, loader, notifydatasetchanged

I have a question.
I am programming a application to add records to a Content Provider.
The content provider is working perfectly.
My problem is when I tried to insert some data into the listview. It inserts, but I'm not able to see the data(Except that I restart the app).
I was calling notifydatasetchanged from the adapter but it didn't work.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements

    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
        ListView listContacts;
        ListView listView;
        Button addContactButton;
        MyAdapter adapter;
        ContentValues values;
        ContentResolver contentResolver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            contentResolver = getContentResolver();
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            values = new ContentValues();
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
            addContactButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            addContactButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Dialog dialogForm = new Dialog(v.getContext());
                    dialogForm.setTitle("Add a new Address");
                    dialogForm.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
                    dialogForm.show();
                    Button saveButton = (Button) dialogForm
                            .findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
                    final EditText addressEditText = (EditText) dialogForm
                            .findViewById(R.id.addressEditText);
                    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                values.put(Contract.DATA, addressEditText.getText()
                                        .toString());
                                contentResolver.insert(
                                        Contract.CONTENT_URI, values);
                                values.clear();
                                dialogForm.dismiss();

                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    ((MyAdapter)listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged() ;
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
            return new CursorLoader(this, Contract.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
            adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, 0);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            adapter.swapCursor(null);

        }

    }
```

Can someone give me a clue about this problem?
Also, I have another question. Is efficient the implementation of onLoadFinished method?

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `restartLoader` to refresh the data inside the listview.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html

when you make changes to ContentProvider data, you must call `getLoaderManager().restartLoader()`.It will discard any old data and `onCreateLoader` will be called again which will in turn fetch updated records and ListView will be updated.

Below is nice tutorial on Loaders.

http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/

Comment: That was very useful Vipul also the tutorial is great. I added getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this); for the button of the dialog and worked!!